# Как узнать установленную скорость выполнения двойного щелчка Windows в Delphi

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, мышь

Как программно узнать текущее значение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть специальная функция:

```
uses Winapi.Windows;

..

t := GetDoubleClickTime;
```

возвращает время в миллисекундах.

---

*Оригинальный ответ на enSO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59305415*
*Справка от Microsoft: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdoubleclicktime*